# How can I update a static property in React component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component with redux state and static property which depends on state. How can I update this static property?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CustomIcon from './CustomIcon';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getTranslate } from 'react-localize-redux';

class ExitButton extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: this.props.translate('exit'), // here
    drawerIcon: <CustomIcon name='sign-out' size={27} withoutFeedback />
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    translate: getTranslate(state.locale)
  })
)(ExitButton);
```

Comment: Please give us some code to reference, in accordance to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you considered component lifecycle methods yet? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: I tried to use lifecycle methods but didn't get anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider creating a separate container and hooking it into the static property.

```
const Translator = ({ translate, text }) => translate(text)
export default connect(
  state => ({
    translate: getTranslate(state.locale)
  })
)(Translator);
```

And then in your `ExitButton` component

```
...
static navigationOptions = {
  drawerLabel: <Translator text='exit'>,
  drawerIcon: <CustomIcon name='sign-out' size={27} withoutFeedback />
}
...
```

I haven't tested this but by HOC [conventions](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-pass-unrelated-props-through-to-the-wrapped-component), should work.